# Showing different pages based on user authenticated or not - should I use multiple routers or combine them into one?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am currently working on a simple React application and I am handling the user authentication right now, so showing the correct pages based on logged in or not. I got a user component which is the first thing that's shown when I start my application. I am currently using the conditional operator "?" to check if a user is already logged in or not, so if I'm not logged in it uses the router in UserComponent to handle the login/register or if I'm already logged in it redirects me to the LoggedInComponent to handle a different router.

UserComponent:

```
export default function UserComponent() {
  const user = useContext(UserContext);
  return (
        user ?
        <LoggedInComponent />
      :
        <BrowserRouter>
          <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={SignIn}/>
          <Route path="/signUp" component={SignUp}/>
          <Route path="/passwordReset" component={PasswordReset}/>
          <Route component={NotFound}/>
          </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>

  );
}
```

LoggedInComponent:

```
export default function LoggedInComponent() {
  return (
        <BrowserRouter>
          <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={DashboardPage}/>
          <Route path="/profile" component={ProfilePage}/>
          <Route component={NotFound}/>
          </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

I was wondering if this is a good way to handle my routes or should I sort of combine them and do the "user authenticated or not" check somewhere inside the router? Because I currently got the issue when I'm logged in that I can see the login form for 2 seconds before it loads the DashboardPage (because they obviously share the same path right now). Should I just fix this issue with a spinner/loading screen or should I rewrite the code and combine both routers into one?

PS: I might wanna mention that I'm not that experienced with React, so I obviously don't know the clean or proper way to structure my projects yet

Comment: Loading screen is a common solution

Comment: It seems fine to me the way you did. I guess the bug you saw is from how you handle the value of `user` (how is it updated?). Are you making some requests to validate the token, cookie ?